# Terrafrom v11.13 Attach Multiple Data Templates To Single Resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm running Terraform v11.13 with the AWS provider. Is it possible to attach multiple data template files to a single resource?

An example of this is where you have a single aws_iam_policy resouce, but for it to create multiple IAM polices from different data template files.

It works when it is just a single data template file with a count index. It also works when the file is static, as in not a template file.

Here is the code example

```
variable "policy_list"{
    type = "list"
    default = ["s3,"emr","lambda"]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "many_policies" {
  count       = "${length(var.policy_list)}"
  name        = "Policy_${var.policy_list[count.index]}_${var.environment}"
  policy      = "${file("${path.module}/files/policies/${var.environment}/${var.policy_list[count.index]}.json")}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "many_policies_attachment" {
   count      = "${length(var.policy_list)}"
   role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_roles.*.name[index(var.role_list, "MyRole"))]}"
   policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.many_policies.*.arn[count.index]}"
}
```

But what fails is

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "many_policies" {
  count       = "${length(var.policy_list)}"
  name        = "Policy_${var.policy_list[count.index]}_${var.environment}"
  policy      = "${data.template_file.${var.policy_list[count.index]}_policy_file.*.rendered[count.index]}"
}
```

With an error message similar to

```
parse error expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$"
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What fails? Can you share a [mcve] of this failing and also include the full error?

Comment: From a low level, variable interpolation inside variable interpolation is not going to be possible. From a high level, dynamic iterations within resources is not going to be possible in Terraform < 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors messages and the suggestion by Matt Schuchard, it's fair to conclude that the **data.template_file** option does not support interpolation in v11.13